# Access to *.scss files in azure angular web app giving 404 (Not found)

Tags: angular, azure, sass, azure-web-app-service

We have an angular web app that requires access to some static scss files in order to download pdf versions of the site.

The files we are trying to access exist within the source when looking at source code:
[image]

However when we try and access these within either the application or directly in the url it is returning 404 Not Found

[image]

Other files within the assets folder are working absolutely fine.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Check if you can access .scss files from your server (e.g. in IIS, you need add a  Managed Handler (in "Handler Mapping") to allow non typicals files)

Comment: How you have deployed your Application ?

Comment: It was deployed through azure devops, not sure how that is relevant? The files exist on the server as you can see in the screenshot. But just cannot access them

Comment: Ok..will check it and let you know.

Comment: @andyb952 - Make sure your `angular.json` file has the styles section with `.scss` file is included.[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yr2Vk.png)

Comment: Once try by placing the `.scss` file directly in the assets folder and check.

Comment: Never fixed this, ended up storing the file as a *.txt and we were then able to get the content. Suspected minification or azure security maybe?